# ArrayList em JAVA

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma pergunta sobre ArrayList

**Exemplo:**  Fiz uma interface gráfica em Java para cadastrar jogadores em um `ArrayList`. após o cadastro, o jogador vai para um `Jlist`, ai que vem minha dúvida. Quero comprar esse jogador para o meu time, eu seleciono ele e clico em comprar e no caso esse método comprar eu só usei um remove. Queria remover ele da lista dos jogadores que estão à venda e colocar ele no meu ***Time***?

Comment: poderia mostrar seu código até o momento?

Comment: Cola o código no post para poder entender melhor

Comment: Se você colocar o código que você fez até o momento a gente consegue colocar seguindo a sua lógica. Fornece, por favor o código.

Comment: Gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789)

Answer (score 1):

Por lógica, do mesmo jeito que você tem um `ArrayList` de jogadores "livres", cada objeto `Time` tem que ter o seu `ArrayList` de jogadores.

Analise melhor isto... pense num histórico do jogador, coloque um objeto `Contrato` aí no meio, onde tem o id do jogador e o id do time, além das datas de inicio e fim do contrato.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem algumas alternativas, entre elas:

- Adicionar o jogador que você selecionou no *ArrayList* `Time` antes de tê-lo removido do *ArrayList* de jogadores à venda:

  ```
  public class Time {
      private ArrayList<Jogador> time; //ArrayList do seu time.
      public Time() {
          time = new ArrayList<>();
      } public adicionarJogador(Jogador a) {
          time.add(a);
      }
  }
  //
  public class Vendedor {
      private ArrayList<Jogador> vendavel; //ArrayList de jogadores à venda, supondo que já existem jogadores nesse ArrayList.
      Time a = new Time();
      public venderJogador() {
          a.adicionarJogador(/*Índice do jogador que você selecionar através da interface.*/);
          vendavel.remove(/*Índice do jogador que você selecionar através da interface.*/);
      }
  ```

  ...