# Buscar um objeto dentro de uma ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Criei uma classe `Conta` e defini seus atributos. Em outra parte do código, defini valores para seus atributos e a adicionei à uma `ArrayList`, agora preciso seleciona-la e printar o valor de um de seus atributos, porém não estou conseguindo, segue o código:

**classe Conta:**

```
public static class Conta {
    //definindo a classe conta

    int numero;
    String nome_titular;
    double saldo;

    //método para depósito
    void depositar(double valor) {
        this.saldo = this.saldo + valor;
    }

    //método para saque
    boolean sacar(double valor) {
        if (valor > this.saldo) {
            return false;
        } else {
            this.saldo = this.saldo - valor;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Definição dos valores dos atributos:**

```
            c.numero = qtdContas;
            System.out.println("Digite o Nome do titular da conta:");
            sc.nextLine();
            c.nome_titular = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite o Saldo da conta:");
            c.saldo = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Conta criada! Numero da conta = " + c.numero);

            Contas.add(c);
```

**Selecionar e printar um de seus atributos:**

```
            if (Contas.isEmpty() == true) {
                System.out.println("Não há contas cadastradas!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
                int nmrConta = sc.nextInt();
                Conta auxiliar = new Conta();
                auxiliar = Contas.get(nmrConta);
                System.out.println(auxiliar.saldo);
            }
```

Comment: Esse código compila? A classe é estática, e você ta dando `new Conta()`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe Conta fica OK se retirar o modificador `static`.
Se usar `static` não poder usar `this`, pois classes estáticas não podem ser instanciadas, isto é, não podem ter objetos criados com o `new`.

Criei uma classe executável com seu código com algumas adaptações para ver rodando. Repare que mantive a essência do código original. 
Nota: As exceções se ocorrerem não estão sendo tratadas.

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestConta
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

        List<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.print("Digite a quantidade de contas que serão criadas:");
        int qtdContas = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("------------------------------");

        for(int i=1; i<=qtdContas; i++)
        {
            Conta c = new Conta();

            //System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
            c.numero = i; //sc.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Digite o Nome do titular da conta:");
            c.nome_titular = sc.next();

            System.out.print("Digite o Saldo da conta:");
            c.saldo = sc.nextDouble();


            System.out.println("Conta criada! Numero da conta = " + c.numero);

            contas.add(c);

            System.out.println("------------------------------");
        }


        System.out.println("=========================================================");

        //Verificando as contas criadas

        if (contas.isEmpty() == true) 
        {
            System.out.println("Não há contas cadastradas!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("Digite o número da conta:");
            int nmrConta = sc.nextInt();
            nmrConta--; //pq ao invés de começar o for de zero, começamos de 1, mas guardamos no elemento 0 do array

            Conta auxiliar = contas.get(nmrConta);
            System.out.println("Nome do titular:" + auxiliar.nome_titular);
            System.out.println("Saldo da conta:" +auxiliar.saldo);
        }            
    }

}
```

Exemplo de output gerado caso sejam digitados dados de maneira correta para não causar exceções:

```
Digite a quantidade de contas que serão criadas:3
------------------------------
Digite o Nome do titular da conta:Lucas
Digite o Saldo da conta:100
Conta criada! Numero da conta = 1
------------------------------
Digite o Nome do titular da conta:Alexandre
Digite o Saldo da conta:500
Conta criada! Numero da conta = 2
------------------------------
Digite o Nome do titular da conta:Diogo
Digite o Saldo da conta:1000
Conta criada! Numero da conta = 3
------------------------------
=========================================================
Digite o número da conta:2
Nome do titular:Alexandre
Saldo da conta:500.0
```

Caso esta resposta tenha sido útil para ajudar a resolver o problema, aceite-a como resposta e dê +1 clicando na setinha para cima para me dar pontos de reputação do site. 
Em caso de dúvidas, pergunte nos comentários.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito, agora está funcionando perfeitamente <3 valeu mesmo

Answer (score 8):

Bom para começa:

> Todas as classes da API Java, classes definidas pelo usuário ou classes de qualquer outra API - estendem a classe java.lang.Object, implícita ou explicitamente. [[MALA GUPTA, 2015](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Java-Programmer-Certification-Guide/dp/161729148X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=OCP+Java+SE+7+Programmer+II+Certification+Guide&qid=1667802858&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74), p. 51]

Tendo isso em mente, quando pensamos em implementar uma classe (**java class design**), no contexto aqui seria a: `class Conta`, temos os aspectos

- Importância do método `equals()` procurando e removendo valores de um ArrayList.
- Importância de `override` do método `equals()`.

Devemos nos preocupar com a seguinte dica:

> Se você estiver adicionando instâncias de uma classe definida pelo usuário como elementos a uma ArrayList, substitua seu método equals () ou então seus métodos `contains()` ou `remove()` podem não se comportar como esperado. [[MALA GUPTA, 2015](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Java-Programmer-Certification-Guide/dp/161729148X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=OCP+Java+SE+7+Programmer+II+Certification+Guide&qid=1667802858&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74), p. 281]

Para evitarmos isso é indicado que se sobrescrever o método `equals()`, no nosso caso, da seguinte forma:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Conta) {
       Conta conta = (Conta)obj;
       /** 
        * Considerando apenas o atributo numero para se comparar os objetos.  
        * Alteração do método `equals()` sugerida pelo @Wryel.
        */
        if (conta.numero == this.numero)
           return true;
￼    }
    return false;
}
```

<sub>**NOTA**: Alteração do método `equals()` sugerida pelo [@Wryel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1479/wryel) seguinda os conceitos de DDD [[Vaughn Vernon, 2013](https://www.amazon.com.br/Implementando-Domain-Driven-design-Vernon/dp/8576089521/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1GQ99CLZ3B3GH&keywords=Domain-Driven+Design+-+DDD&qid=1667802966&sprefix=domain-driven+design+-+ddd%2Caps%2C290&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1)].</sub>

Para uma abordagem geral temos:

> Regras para sobrescrita do método `equals()`
>
> Método `equals()` define um contrato elaborado (conjunto de regras), da seguinte forma (diretamente da documentação da API Java):
>
> **1. É reflexivo** - Para qualquer valor de referência não nulo x, x.equals (x) deve retornar true. Esta regra estabelece que um objeto deve ser igual a si mesmo, o que é razoável.
>
> **2. É simétrico** - Para quaisquer valores de referência não nulos x e y, x.equals(y) deve retornar true se e somente se y.equals(x) retorna true. Esta regra estabelece que dois objetos devem ser comparáveis ​​entre si da mesma maneira.
>
> **3. É transitivo** - Para quaisquer valores de referência não nulos x, y, e z, se x.equals (y) retorna true e y.equals (z) retorna true, então x.equals (z) deve retornar true. Esta regra indica que, ao comparar objetos, você não deve comparar seletivamente os valores com base no tipo de um objeto.
>
> **4. É consistente** - Para quaisquer valores de referência não nulos xey, as múltiplas invocações de x.equals (y) retornam consistentemente true ou consistentemente retornam false, desde que nenhuma informação usada em comparações de igual nos objetos seja modificada. Esta regra indica que o método equals () deve contar com o valor das variáveis ​​de instância que podem ser acessadas a partir da memória e não deve tentar confiar em valores como o endereço IP de um sistema, que pode ser atribuído um valor separado após a reconexão para uma rede.
>
> **5.** - Para qualquer valor de referência não nulo x, x.equals(null) deve retornar false. Esta regra indica que um objeto não nulo nunca pode ser igual a null.

É bom considerar também:

> Um método indevidamente que sobrescreve o método `equals()` não significa falha na compilação.[[MALA GUPTA, 2015](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Java-Programmer-Certification-Guide/dp/161729148X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=OCP+Java+SE+7+Programmer+II+Certification+Guide&qid=1667802858&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74), p. 58]

É relevante entender que um ArrayList é um objeto da interface List, e que no nosso contexto da pergunta é usado o método `get()` marcado abaixo:

[image: List Interfaces]

FONTE: Figure 4.12 Métodos da interface List, agrupados pela sua funcionalidade [[MALA GUPTA, 2015](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Java-Programmer-Certification-Guide/dp/161729148X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=OCP+Java+SE+7+Programmer+II+Certification+Guide&qid=1667802858&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74), p. 277]

<sub>**NOTA**: Existe considerações sobre a nacessidade de sobrescrita do método `hashCode()`, mas acredito foge do escopo da pergunta.</sub>

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[MALA GUPTA, 2015], **[OCP Java SE 7 Programmer II Certification Guide](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Java-Programmer-Certification-Guide/dp/161729148X/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=OCP+Java+SE+7+Programmer+II+Certification+Guide&qid=1667802858&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.6a09f7ec-d911-4889-ad70-de8dd83c8a74)**: PREPARE FOR THE 1ZO-804 EXAM</sub> 
<sub>[Vaughn Vernon, 2013], **[Domain-Driven Design - DDD](https://www.amazon.com.br/Implementando-Domain-Driven-design-Vernon/dp/8576089521/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1GQ99CLZ3B3GH&keywords=Domain-Driven+Design+-+DDD&qid=1667802966&sprefix=domain-driven+design+-+ddd%2Caps%2C290&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1)**: Implementing Domain-Driven Design</sub>

Comment: se você mudar a implementação do método equals para apenas checar o número da conta, a regra do algoritmo ficará correta :o)

Comment: @wryel, sim pode ser, sim. Mas quem garante que em algum lugar do algo algoritmo seja adicionado um objeto conta1 [número=333, saldo 25.00] diferente. E tenha que remover este mesmo objeto? E foi encontrado como primeira ocorrência obj1[número=333, saldo 27.00] o método equals() retornará o obj1 erradamente porque só considerou o atributo numero.

Comment: o contrato do equals é justamente representar a igualdade entre dois objetos. De acordo com o conceito de conta (no mundo real), uma conta só é a mesma que a outra se o número das conta forem iguais não ? rs

Comment: Verdade! Vc tem toda a razão. Buscando modelar usando os conceitos de [Domain Driven Design - DDD](https://ebooks-it.org/0321834577-ebook.htm). Ótimo comentário!