# É possivel instanciar ArrayList dinamicamente em java?

Tags: java

Por exemplo, se eu precisar criar arraylists para cada pessoa q se cadastra no meu sistema:

```
ArrayList pessoa1 ArrayList();
ArrayList pessoa2 ArrayList();
ArrayList pessoa3 ArrayList();
```

O problema é que nao sei quantas pessoas vao se cadastrar entao teria q ser criado dinamicamente, tipo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numeroPessoasCadastradas; i++){
    pessoa[i] = new ArrayList();
}
```

É possivel fazer algo desse tipo?

Comment: Sim, perfeitamente possivel. ArrayList não tem tamanho definido. Ele até tem um tamanho mas vai expandindo a medida que vai sendo preenchido.

Comment: Ola, tentei criar dessa for mas o java me retorna o seguinte erro: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Então seria interessante explicar melhor o problema, porque não ficou muito claro o objetivo disso.

Comment: Provavelmente o ArrayList `pessoa` não foi criado.

Comment: Tenta iniciar `pessoa` antes.Você está usando um vetor de `ArrayList`, o que me é estranho; de qualquer forma, você poderia, antes do `for`, fazer `pessoa = new ArrayList[numeroPessoasCadastradas]`, mas é muito estranho fazer isso. Qual o contexto de você precisar fazer isso? Por que os `ArrayList`s não estão tipados?

Comment: @Thiago, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta. Na sua solução vc usa a ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, só que, da maneira que você escreveu, `pessoa[]` é só um `Array`, e `Arrays` não crescem dinamicamente como você gostaria:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MeuPequenoArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numeroPessoasCadastradas = 12345; // tamanho fixo
        ArrayList[] pessoa = new ArrayList[numeroPessoasCadastradas];

        for (int i = 0; i < numeroPessoasCadastradas; i++) {
            pessoa[i] = new ArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Uma possível solução, é criar um `List` de `ArrayLists` - ou um `ArrayList` de `ArrayLists`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MeuEnormeArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numeroPessoasCadastradas = 12; // esse número não importa mais
        ArrayList<ArrayList> pessoa = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numeroPessoasCadastradas; i++){
            pessoa.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta. Na sua solução vc usa a ArrayList.