# Ordenar Collection

Tags: java, collection

Possuo uma classe chamada **Objeto** e dentro dela possui uma Coleção de **Eventos**, resumindo é assim:

```
public class Objeto{

private Collection<Evento> eventos;
}
```

Na classe Evento, tenho meus atributos e dentre eles, possuo um:

```
@Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date horario;
```

Na minha tela eu vou obter um `Collection` de Objeto. Eu preciso do seguinte:

Se na minha classe Evento que está dentro de Objeto eu possuo o campo `horario`. Preciso que minha `Collection` de Objeto seja ordenada em ordem decrescente ao `horario`. Ex:

```
10/12/2015 10:00
10/12/2015 09:00
...
```

Tentei assim mas sem sucesso:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Collection<Objeto> ordenarLista() {
        Collection<Objeto> objetos = service.findAll();
        Collection<Objeto> lista = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        Date referencia = new Date("10/01/2000 00:00:00");
        for (Objeto objeto : objetos) {
            for (Evento evento : objeto.getEventos()){
                if (evento.getHorario().after(referencia)){
                    lista.add(objeto);
                    referencia = evento.getHorario();
                }
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta. Na sua solução vc usa a interface Collection que por sua vez é a interface pai da interface List.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando Java 8, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
List<Evento> lista = new ArrayList<>(service.findAll());
lista.sort(new Comparator<Evento>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Evento o1, Evento o2) {
        return o1.getHorario().compareTo(o2.getHorario());
    }
});
return lista;
```

Se estiver usando Java 7 ou anterior, também há o `Collections.sort`:

```
List<Evento> lista = new ArrayList<>(service.findAll());
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<Evento>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Evento o1, Evento o2) {
        return o1.getHorario().compareTo(o2.getHorario());
    }
});
return lista;
```

Note que o exemplo não está `null-safe`, mas isso é um tratamento rápido normalmente

#### EDIT

Douglas percebeu que minhas sugestões tem probelmas tem problemas. Considerando que dentro de `Objeto` tenho um `List` de `Evento`, quer-se que o `Objeto` que tenha o evento mais tardio apareça na frete:

```
List<Objecto> objetos = new ArrayList<>(service.findAll());
// ordenar todos os eventos dentro de cada objeto
for (Objeto obj: objetos) {
    obj.getEventos().sort(new Comparator<Evento>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Evento o1, Evento o2) {
            // invertendo a ordem, primeiro os eventos maiores
            return -o1.getHorario().compareTo(o2.getHorario());
        }
    });
}
// ordenar usando como base o maior dos eventos
objetos.sort(new Comparator<Objeto>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Objeto o1, Objeto o2) {
            // levando em comparação os maiores eventos que, devido à ordenação anterior, estão em obj.getEventos().get(0)
            return -o1.getEventos().get(0).getHorario().compareTo(o2.getEventos().get(0).getHorario());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Meu findAll retorna lista de Objetos e não de Evento.

Comment: Defina um jeito de como você quer ordenar o `Objeto` então. Creio que em `Objeto` você quer uma _bag_ (_bag_: multiconjunto, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiconjunto) ordenada, portanto, nestes casos, deveria usar `List`, não apenas `Collection`. Pelo que li, você quer ordenar `Objeto` usando seu `Evento` que acontece mais posteriormente, é isso:

Comment: Exato, eu inclusive troquei de Collection pra List.

Comment: Douglas, alterei minha resposta. Olha ali após o **EDIT**, deve satisfazer suas necessidades. Qualquer coisa, tem um post da Caelum ensinando a usar o `Comparator` no Java: http://blog.caelum.com.br/ordenando-colecoes-com-comparable-e-comparator/

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta. Na sua solução vc usa o objeto ArrayList que por sua vez é um objeto da interface List.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `features` do Java 8, como [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), para simplificar o trabalho, conforme segue:

```
List<Evento> eventos = objeto.getEventos();
eventos.sort(Comparator.comparing(Evento::getHorario))
```

Neste caso a lista de evento ficará ordenada em ordem crescente de Horario.

Como você quer decrescente, utilize o `comparator reversed`:

```
List<Evento> eventos = objeto.getEventos();
eventos.sort(Comparator.comparing(Evento::getHorario).reversed())
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas eu quero ordenar a lista de objetos, irá funcionar neste caso ?

Comment: Sim. Se você estiver usando Java 8, em `List` tem o método `sort(Comparator)`, em que você passa o comparator desejado e a lista é ordenada. Note que `Collection` é um _bag_ desordenado; coisas ordenadas implementam `List`

Comment: Tem certeza? Que horas eu altero o List de Objetos ?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta. Na sua solução vc usa a interface List.