# Como armazenar Strings splitadas em um ArrayList?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho no qual preciso salvar as informações de uma conta corrente,  preciso ler as informações de um arquivo(texto) e splitar essas informações pra dividir em **código da conta**, **nome** e **saldo**. Além disso, preciso salvar essas informações em um Array.

Meu problema é o seguinte: eu não consigo splitar essas informações para salvar num Array. Será que poderiam me ajudar?

Eu criei uma função leitor();

```
public void leitor() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{ 
    try (
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("arquivo.txt"));
        ) {
             for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
                 **String saida = line.split(";");**
                 System.out.println(saida);
             }
        }
}
```

Que apenas lê as informações do arquivo, entretanto, eu não consigo splitar essas informações.

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta. Por causa das tags array e arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Veja uma forma simples usando o método estático `Arrays.asList()`, porém "splintando" espaços:

```
String str = "A HBO anunciou a sétima temporada de Game of Thrones";       
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
```

Para que seja separado por ponto e virgula, mas colocar `.split(";")`;

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta.

Comment: @pss1suporte não entendi exatamente o que você quer! xD

Comment: Não, não .... apenas o uso de ArrayList e entender que são objetos da interface List. e adicionado a referencia da minha resposta pode ajudar no entendimento do uso. Entende!?

Comment: @pss1suporte pode usar a vontade como referência. Essa resposta ajuda muito bem o Chief, porém ele perguntou e sumiu. Acontece muito isso por aqui. Pena que a resposta fica sem validar. Mas eu garanto, isso funciona. =D abs

Comment: Eu acredito que respondemos para toda a comunidade, claro que a validação do autor é muito útil, mas não é o único propósito que me motiva em responder.

Comment: @pss1suporte é para comunidade sim, mas a validação do autor é mais uma prova, além da minha que, o código funciona. Lembrando quando há outras respostas dependendo da situação, há várias formas de resolver um problema. Ai a avaliação de qual resposta é mais viável, é não aquela que está validada, mas sim aquela que tem maior reputação.

Comment: Verdade! Mas mesmo quando não funciona, é ótimo também porque aprendemos da mesma forma e com mais profundidade. Reputação representa privilégios e é auto-regulado e por meritocracia. Concordo com vc!

Answer (score -3):

em vez de fazeres `String saida = line.split(";");`

faz

```
var saida = line.split(';');
```

ou então declaras `string[] saida`

Comment: var? Isso não existe em java.