# Como definir a comparação de igualdade entre dois objectos presentes num ArrayList?

Tags: java, classes, lista, arraylist, collection

Como posso definir o comportamento de comparação da igualdade entre dois objectos cuja classe é definida por mim que estão armazenados num objecto do tipo ArrayList?

NomeCor.java

```
public class NomeCor {
  private String nome;

  public String obterNome() { return nome; }

  public NomeCor(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

}
```

No método main:

```
    NomeCor verde1 = new NomeCor("verde");
    NomeCor verde2 = new NomeCor("verde");
    ArrayList<NomeCor> lista = new ArrayList<NomeCor>();
    lista.add(verde1);
    lista.add(verde2);
    if (lista.get(0) == lista.get(1)) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0) == verde1) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0) == verde2) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
```

Log de Consola:

Não existe igualdade

Existe igualdade

Não existe igualdade

Comment: Não entendi qual é a pergunta.. como o arraylist determina a igualdade de quais objetos exatamente?

Comment: Eu acho que seria totalmente válido se a pergunta fosse somente isso e nada mais além disso: "Como a classe ArrayList determinada a igualdade dos objetos". Se quiser, posso tentar editar a pergunta para exemplo didático, para orientá-lo melhor como adaptar uma pergunta ao escopo do site.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, pronto! Apenas coloquei um contexto! E gostaria de deixar registrado e reforçar: Modelagem de Classes em Java (Class Java Design) é muito relevante e os recursos da linguagem devem ser bem divulgados e discutidos. Obrigado pela atenção! Nosso objetivo é contribuir com eficácia.

Comment: @pss1suporte sim, mas não se trata de uma "discussão". Para estar no escopo do site, a pergunta deve ser bem definida (um problema bem descrito para que possa surgir uma resposta bem descrita). Da forma que foi colocada, não dá pra entender o propósito real da pergunta. Outra dica: Eu acho que a sua pergunta não precisa de referências :)

Comment: @pss1suporte portanto a pergunta real é como posso definir o comportamento de comparação da igualdade entre dois objectos cuja class é definida por mim que estão armazenados num objecto do tipo ArrayList?

Comment: @PedroFerreira você pode entrar no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) principal para tirar mais dúvidas com a gente :)

Comment: @PedroFerreira, isso mesmo! Estou aprendendo a formular perguntas mais eficientes, o WallaceMaxters tá me ajudando muito.

Comment: Gostaria de deixar um adendo com esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

A comparação entre dois objectos da mesma classe é feita por herança da classe Object, que efectua uma comparação por referência as posições na memória, dai `verde1` ser diferente de `verde2` quando comparado.
Para obter uma comparação mais precisa, será necessário efectuar override ao método `.equal(Object objecto)` da classe parente Object para definirmos o processo de comparação.

NomeCor.java

```
public class NomeCor {

  private String nome;

  public String obterNome() { return nome; }

  public NomeCor(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object objecto) {
    if (objecto == null) return false;
    if (objecto.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
    NomeCor aComparar = (NomeCor) objecto;
    if (!this.nome.equals(aComparar.obterNome()))
        return false;
    else
        return true;  
    }
}
```

No método main:

```
    NomeCor verde1 = new NomeCor("verde");
    NomeCor verde2 = new NomeCor("verde");
    ArrayList<NomeCor> lista = new ArrayList<NomeCor>();
    lista.add(verde1);
    lista.add(verde2);
    if (lista.get(0).equals(lista.get(1))) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0).equals(verde1)) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0).equals(verde2)) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
```

No log da consola, surgirá o resultado pretendido:

Existe igualdade

Existe igualdade

Existe igualdade

Comment: Gostaria de deixar um adendo com esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

## Comparação de objetos em Java

Note que estamos falando entre comparar se dois objetos são iguais ou não!

Para isso existe na linguagem Java dois métodos fundamentais chamados **equals(...)** e **hashCode()** que são declarados na classe `java.lang.Object` por padrão e são parte da biblioteca principal (core) do Java.

***Você deve implementar esses dois métodos em suas classes que precisam ser comparadas***!

O método `equals()` é usado para comparar se um objeto é igual o outro.

O método `hashCode()` é usado para gerar um número de identificação correspondente ao objeto.

Boa parte das classes padrões da linguagem Java usam esses métodos para poder inserir e capturar objetos em uma lista, também para evitar duplicidades de objetos como o caso do HashSet por exemplo.

A implementação padrão dentro do objeto `java.lang.Object` utiliza o método equals para comparar o endereço de memória entre os objetos, e o método retorna "true" se ambos objetos referenciam/apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória.

Mas a linguagem recomenda que esses métodos sejam re-escritos (Override) para que eles definam alguma forma lógica ou de negócio para comparar o objeto. Por exemplo a classe `java.lang.String`
sobrescreve esses métodos para comparar
o seu conteúdo, para retornar "true" se dois objetos possuem a mesma cadeia de caracteres.

#### Algumas regras são recomendadas na implementação

- *Reflexão*: Objetos devem ser iguais a si mesmos; `o.equals(o) == true`
- *Simetria*: Se o objeto "a" é igual ao o objeto "b" `(a.equals(b));` Então "b" deve ser igual a "a".
- *Transição*: Se `a.equals(b) == true` e `b.equals(c) == true` então `c.equals(a)` deve ser true.
- *Consistência*: Várias chamadas consecutivas do método `equals()` deve sempre retornar o mesmo resultado enquanto nenhuma propriedade do objeto não for modificada.
- *Comparação com Null*: A comparação com um objeto nulo (null) numca deve retornar `NullPointerException` e deve ser tratado como false; a.equals(null) == false

#### Contrato de relação entre equals() e hashCode()

- Se dois objetos são iguais pelo método `equals()` então o resultado do método `hashCode()` deve ser o mesmo.
- Se dois objetos não são iguais pelo método `equals()` então o resultado do `hashCode()` pode ser o mesmo ou não.

#### Passo-a-Passo para sobrescrever o método equals()

1. Valide usando `this`, se iguais retorne true
2. Valide se null, se nulo retorne false
3. Valide se o objeto é do mesmo tipo usando `instanceof`, se não é, retorne false
4. Tente fazer o cast do objeto
5. Compare os atributos do objeto começando pelos valores numéricos. Se não forem iguais retorne false

*OBS: Não confunda essa comparação com a comparação de grandeza dos valores de um objeto; se um valor é menor ou maior que o outro, por exemplo, nesse caso teríamos que abordar a implementação das interfaces *Comparable* e *Comparator* do Java.*

Exemplo

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Carro {

    private String modelo;
    private String cor;
    private int ano;

    public Carro(String modelo, String cor, int ano) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.cor = cor;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    
        Carro c = (Carro) o;
        if(ano != c.ano) return false;
        if(!modelo.equals(c.modelo)) return false;
        return cor.equals(c.cor);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (modelo != null ? modelo.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (cor != null ? cor.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + ano;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return modelo + "," + cor + "," + ano;
    }

    public static void main(String args) {

        List<Carro> listaCarros = new ArrayList<Carro>();
        listaCarros.add(new Carro("Ford","Azul",2017))
        listaCarros.add(new Carro("Honda","Preto",2016))
        listaCarros.add(new Carro("Toyota","Branco",2015))
    
        Carro meuCarro = new Carro("Honda","Preto",2016);
    
        for(Carro carro : listaCarros) {
             if(carro.equals(meuCarro)) {
                 System.out.println("O Carro "+carro+" é iqual ao meu!");
             }
        }
    
    } 

}
```

*Referências*

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: gostaria de deixar um adendo com esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta. O interessante da sua resposta é complemento e contraste com o método hashCode().

Comment: Seria interessante se vc apresentasse uma possível implementação dele. Isso contribuiria muito com a comunidade! E colocar um referência seria bom.

Comment: Obrigado pela respostas! O critério que considerei foi por ser mais completa abordando hashCode(), colocando exemplo de código e referência.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você deve entender como o java faz comparação estre duas variáveis.

Para para variaveis de tipo primitivo como short, int, float, double, long, char, byte, (Basicamente todas os tipos que começam com letra minuscula) deve-se usar == para compara duas variáveis.

Para variáveis de tipos de classes como Object, String, ou qualque classe que você criar ou de alguma API deve-se usar o método equals(), como boa pratica de programação todas as classe criadas deve ter o método equals() sobrescrito, ao usar == para esses tipo o java vai comparar se as duas variáveis estão no mesmo lugar na memoria ou seja referenciando o mesmo objeto na memoria.

Porem Classes como Integer, Float, Double, Long, pode-se usar == para fazer comparação desde que uma das variaveis sejam de tipo primitivo, por exemplo.

```
Integer n1 = 1;
Integer n2 = 1;
int n3 = 0;

System.out.println(n1 == n2);//false
System.out.println(n1 == n3);//true
System.out.println(n1.equals(n2));//true
```

Porem o se a variável do n1 fosse null o java lançaria uma NullPointerException com a expressão n1 == n3.

Para que seu código funcione corretamente siga o exemplo abaixo.

NomeCor.java

```
public class NomeCor {

  private String nome;

  public String obterNome() { return nome; }

  public NomeCor(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object objecto) {
    if (objecto == null) return false;
    if (objecto.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
    NomeCor aComparar = (NomeCor) objecto;

    if(this.nome == null && aComparar.obterNome() != null){
        return false;

    return this.nome.equals(aComparar.obterNome());
}
```

No método main:

```
    NomeCor verde1 = new NomeCor("verde");
    NomeCor verde2 = new NomeCor("verde");
    ArrayList<NomeCor> lista = new ArrayList<NomeCor>();
    lista.add(verde1);
    lista.add(verde2);
    if (lista.get(0).equals(lista.get(1))) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0).equals(verde1)) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
    if (lista.get(0).equals(verde2)) {
        System.out.println("Existe igualdade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não existe igualdade");
    }
```

Leitura adicional.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/comparar-variaveis-ou-equals/564747

https://sergiotaborda.wordpress.com/desenvolvimento-de-software/java/igualdade-em-java/

http://java-i9se.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/igualdade-em-java-equals-e-hashcode.html

Comment: gostaria de deixar um adendo com esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta.