# Java.Util.Set não adiciona novos elementos

Tags: java

Na variavel loja ao tentar adicionar um novo elemento do tipo "Loja" ele sempre fica somente com um elemento e não adiciona um novo elemento. E nunca adiciona um novo. Segue os codigos:
Metodo main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        Set<Integer> idsLojas = new HashSet<>();
        idsLojas.add(123);
        idsLojas.add(333);
        idsLojas.add(3333);

        Set<Loja> lojas = new HashSet<>();
        for (Integer idLoja : idsLojas) {
            lojas.add(new Loja(idLoja));
        }
        usuario.setLojas(lojas);

        System.out.println(usuario.getLojas().size());
    }
```

Construtor de loja:

```
public Loja(Integer id) {
        this.setId(id);

    }
```

O resultado sempre é 1, mesmo eu adicionando 3 valores.

Comment: E a variável local `lojas`, tem apenas um único elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobrescreva os métodos `equals()` e `hashcode()` da classe `Loja`. De preferência deixe o seu IDE criá-los por você. Quando ele lhe pedir por quais critérios especificar os métodos adicione o id da loja como critério.

Leia mais aqui: [Como definir a comparação de igualdade entre dois objectos presentes num ArrayList?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194602/como-definir-a-compara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-igualdade-entre-dois-objectos-presentes-num-arrayli/195634?r=SearchResults#195634)

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja no `Usuario`: o `setLojas` ou o `getLojas` podem estar fazendo bobeiras. Não há garantias disso pois o código não foi mostrado

Comment: Não sei se o problema é esse, pois sem sobrescrever `equals` e `hashCode` o código já funciona (cria um `Set` com 3 lojas): https://ideone.com/fkd5Fy - se o `Set` dele está com 1 elemento, o problema pode estar em outro lugar (ou então ele implementou `equals` e `hashcode` da maneira errada, isso explicaria o `Set` estar com apenas 1 elemento: https://ideone.com/hfprQ3)

Comment: Aproveitando, a implementação de `hashCode` do Java _normalmente_ faz com que 2 objetos distintos tenham códigos de _hash_  distintos, e o `equals` meio que valida pela referência do objeto (não o conteúdo, já que a mesma referência implica mesmo conteúdo) [esse comentário é basicamente o do @hkotsubo, mas comecei a escrevê-lo antes de ver que o hkotsubo havia comentado]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tem razão. Não me atentei ao fato que o Object.equals() deveria ser suficiente para comparar as instâncias de Loja no Set. Então esqueçam tudo o que falei (ou não, é bom saber).

Comment: O erro estava acontecendo por causa do hashCode e equals, por que o set, a lista, estava reconhecendo como objetos duplicados.

Comment: Eu não cheguei a entender o que aconteceu do "set reconhecer como objetos duplicados", mas se ajudou, beleza. :)