# JSONObject não adiciona ArrayList

Tags: java, json, arraylist

Utilizo o código abaixo para popular meus arrays tranquilamente, porém ao pesquisar um tópico por aqui, percebi que para o meu problema poderia utilizar uma classe genérica. O problema é que o JSONObject não está populando com o array passado.

```
class GenProjeto {
    int codigo;
    String nome;
    int qtdeHistoricos;
    int qtdeZeros;
    double media;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Projeto{" + "codigo=" + codigo + ", nome=" + nome + ", qtdeHistoricos=" + qtdeHistoricos + ", qtdeZeros=" + qtdeZeros + ", media=" + media + '}';
    }
}    

List<GenProjeto> projetos = new ArrayList<>();

while (rs.next()) {
    GenProjeto projeto = new GenProjeto();

    projeto.codigo = rs.getInt("his_proj_codigo");
    projeto.nome = rs.getString("proj_nome");
    projeto.qtdeHistoricos = rs.getInt("qtde_historicos");
    projeto.qtdeZeros = rs.getInt("qtde_zeros");
    projeto.media = rs.getDouble("media");

    // exibe o conteudo
    System.out.println(projeto);

    projetos.add(projeto);
}

// exibe o conteudo
System.out.println(projetos);    

JSONObject resposta = new JSONObject();
resposta.put("projetos", projetos);

// exibe vazio
// {"projetos":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
System.out.println(resposta);
return resposta;
```

Comment: Billy Jow, acredito que a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789) pode ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Comment: @pss1suporte, Agradeço a colaboração, porém não entendi a relação dos métodos citados no comentário com o add.

Comment: O uso da class ArrayList com como tipo da interface List. Você tem que pensar no Designer da class GenProjeto tem que sobrescrever os métodos ´equals()´ e ´hashCode()´.

Comment: E tem outra coisa, o modificador de acesso dos campos da classe GenProjeto estão definidas como default. Isso significa que todas as classes devem ficar no mesmo pacote. Caso contrário os valores não serão acessados.

Comment: De qual pacote é a classe `JSONObject` que você está usando?

Comment: A classe GenProjeto é genérica, portanto foi declarada na mesma classe a qual estou utilizando. Só está servindo como forma ou como "record", como fazemos em C++. A classe JSONObject é da lib org.json.