# Erro ao converter um dados de uma classe para outra

Tags: java, jsf

Estou usando o JSF em um projeto, tenho uma tela "W-A" funcionando que exibe os dados da tabela "T-A" em uma grid. Nessa grid, cada linha tem um botão que encaminha para uma nova tela "W-B" onde serão exibidos o "detalhamento" do item da tela anterior em uma grid, e esses itens se encontram na tabela "T-B", que possui como chave estrangeira a chave primária da tabela "T-A".

O problema é que quando eu clico nesse botão tenho como retorno o seguinte erro:

```
AVISO: Cannot convert com.model.Log@5a86506a of type class com.model.Log to class com.model.LogIntegracao
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert com.model.Log@5a86506a of type class com.model.Log to class com.model.LogIntegracao
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:438)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:46)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:204)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:778)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:915)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

O meu Bean está da seguinte maneira:

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.DAO.LogDAO;
import com.controller.Conexao;

@ManagedBean(name = "LogMB")
@SessionScoped
public class LogBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Log log;
    private List<Log> logs;
    private EntradaFiltroLog entradaLog;
    private RetornoFiliais filiais;
    private RetornoIntegracoes integracoes;
    private int[] filiaisSelecionadas;
    private String[] integracoesSelecionadas;
    private LogIntegracao serv;

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public Log getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLog(Log log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public List<Log> getLogs() {
        return logs;
    }

    public void setLogs(List<Log> logs) {
        this.logs = logs;
    }

    public EntradaFiltroLog getEntradaLog() {
        return entradaLog;
    }

    public void setEntradaLog(EntradaFiltroLog entradaLog) {
        this.entradaLog = entradaLog;
    }

    public List<Integer> getFiliais() {
        return filiais.getFiliais();
    }

    public void setFiliais(RetornoFiliais filiais) {
        this.filiais = filiais;
    }

    public List<String> getIntegracoes() {
        return integracoes.getIntegracoes();
    }

    public void setIntegracoes(RetornoIntegracoes integracoes) {
        this.integracoes = integracoes;
    }

    public int[] getFiliaisSelecionadas() {
        return filiaisSelecionadas;
    }

    public void setFiliaisSelecionadas(int[] filiaisSelecionadas) {
        this.filiaisSelecionadas = filiaisSelecionadas;
    }

    public String[] getIntegracoesSelecionadas() {
        return integracoesSelecionadas;
    }

    public void setIntegracoesSelecionadas(String[] integracoesSelecionadas) {
        this.integracoesSelecionadas = integracoesSelecionadas;
    }

    public LogIntegracao getServ(Log log) {
        return new LogIntegracao(log);
    }

    public void setServ(LogIntegracao serv) {
        this.serv = serv;
    }

    public void setFiltroFilialIntegracao() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = Conexao.getConnection();
        filiais = LogDAO.buscarFilaisLogs(conn);
        if (!filiais.getFiliais().isEmpty()) {
            integracoes = LogDAO.buscarIntegracoesLogs(conn);
        }
    }

    public LogBean() {
        try {
            setFiltroFilialIntegracao();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.log = new Log();
        this.entradaLog = new EntradaFiltroLog();
        logs = setLogs();
    }

    private List<Log> setLogs() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = Conexao.getConnection();
            RetornoLogsExistentes retorno = new RetornoLogsExistentes();
            retorno.setLogs(LogDAO.retornaLogs(conn, entradaLog));
            this.log = new Log();
            setLogs(retorno.getLogs());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return logs;

    }

    public void BuscarLogs() {
        Connection conn = null;
        logs = new ArrayList<Log>();
        try {
            conn = Conexao.getConnection();
            entradaLog.setFiliais(filiaisSelecionadas);
            entradaLog.setIntegracoes(integracoesSelecionadas);
            RetornoLogsExistentes retorno = new RetornoLogsExistentes();
            retorno.setLogs(LogDAO.retornaLogs(conn, entradaLog));

            setLogs(retorno.getLogs());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String exibeInconsistencias() {
        return "orq0900a.xhtml";
    }
}
```

A classe Log está assim:

```
package com.model;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Log {

    private int id_logint;
    private int filial;
    private int id_integracao;
    private Date dataexecucao;
    private String conteudoenv;
    private String conteudorec;
    private int status;
    private String descrocorr;
    private String integracao;

    public int getId_logint() {
        return id_logint;
    }

    public void setId_logint(int id_logint) {
        this.id_logint = id_logint;
    }

    public int getFilial() {
        return filial;
    }

    public void setFilial(int filial) {
        this.filial = filial;
    }

    public int getId_integracao() {
        return id_integracao;
    }

    public void setId_integracao(int id_integracao) {
        this.id_integracao = id_integracao;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return dataexecucao;
    }

    public void setData(Date dataexecucao) {
        this.dataexecucao = dataexecucao;
    }

    public String getConteudoenv() {
        return conteudoenv;
    }

    public void setConteudoenv(String conteudoenv) {
        this.conteudoenv = conteudoenv;
    }

    public String getConteudorec() {
        return conteudorec;
    }

    public void setConteudorec(String conteudorec) {
        this.conteudorec = conteudorec;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getDescrocorr() {
        return descrocorr;
    }

    public void setDescrocorr(String descrocorr) {
        this.descrocorr = descrocorr;
    }

    public String getIntegracao() {
        return integracao;
    }

    public void setIntegracao(String integracao) {
        this.integracao = integracao;
    }
}
```

E a classe LogIntegracao assim:

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

public class LogIntegracao implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id_logint;
    private int filial;
    private Date data;
    private int sequencia;
    private String integracao;
    private String chave;
    private String inconsistencia;
    private int status;

    public int getId_logint() {
        return id_logint;
    }

    public void setId_logint(int id_logint) {
        this.id_logint = id_logint;
    }

    public int getFilial() {
        return filial;
    }

    public void setIdFilial(int filial) {
        this.filial = filial;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getSequencia() {
        return sequencia;
    }

    public void setSequencia(int sequencia) {
        this.sequencia = sequencia;
    }

    public String getIntegracao() {
        return integracao;
    }

    public void setIntegracao(String integracao) {
        this.integracao = integracao;
    }

    public String getChave() {
        return chave;
    }

    public void setChave(String chave) {
        this.chave = chave;
    }

    public String getInconsistencia() {
        return inconsistencia;
    }

    public void setInconsistencia(String inconsistencia) {
        this.inconsistencia = inconsistencia;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

E esse é o código do botão na tela (o #{item} é do tipo Log e o #{LogMB.serv} do tipo LogIntegracao):

```
<p:column headerText="Opções"
    style="width:150px;text-align: center">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-wrench"
      title="Reprocessar Inconsistencia"
      action="#{LogMB.exibeInconsistencias}">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}"
          target="#{LogMB.serv}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser solucionado de muitas maneiras, mas sou inclinado a pensar no design e na reutilização da class Log.

```
interface Log {
    /* 
     * Coloque aqui os campos (final static) que tenha em comum 
     * com as classes LogIntegracao e Log
     */

    //Coloque os métodos das que tenha em comum
}

public class LogImp implements Log {
    //Implementação da sua class Log descrita acima
}

public class LogIntegracao implements Serializable, Log {
    //Impelentação da sua class LogIntegracao descrita acima
}
```

Pelo que entendi do erro:

```
AVISO: Cannot convert com.model.Log@5a86506a of type class com.model.Log to class com.model.LogIntegracao
```

As classes não são do mesmo tipo, fazendo com que as classes implementem a mesma interface onde, em teoria, poderiamos instânciar as duas classes em um tipo em comum:

```
Log logImp = new LogImp();                //instância do LogImp do tipo Log
Log logIntegracao = new LogIntegracao();  //instância do LogIntegracao do tipo Log
```

Sempre que projetar classes em java devemos nos preocupar com a seguinte dica:

> Se você estiver adicionando instâncias de uma classe definida pelo usuário como elementos a uma ArrayList, substitua seu método equals () ou então seus métodos `contains()` ou `remove()` podem não se comportar como esperado. [[MALA GUPTA, 2015](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/161729148X), p. 281]

<sub>**Nota**: mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789).</sub>

<sub>**Observação**: é de senso comum agrupar os campos do mesmo tipo:</sub>

```
private int id_logint;
private int filial;
private int status;
private int id_integracao;
private String conteudoenv;
private String conteudorec;
private String descrocorr;
private String integracao;
private Date dataexecucao;
```

Espero ter ajudado!

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[MALA GUPTA, 2015], **[OCP Java SE 7 Programmer II Certification Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/161729148X)**: PREPARE FOR THE 1ZO-804 EXAM</sub>