# Uso do "Instance of"

Tags: java, classes, instanciar-objeto

```
public class AlunoLicenciatura extends Aluno{
    private String curso;
    private ArrayList<Disciplina> l_dis;

    public AlunoLicenciatura(String curso,Aluno a){

        super(a.getNumero(),a.getNome());//recebe o numero e o nome de aluno do objecto do tipo aluno ,neste caso, a1 de acordo com o main
        this.curso=curso;
        this.l_dis=new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
    }
}
```

> 

```
public class Aluno {
    private int numero;
    private String nome;


    public Aluno(){
        this.nome="";
        this.numero=0;
    }

    public Aluno(int numero,String nome){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.numero=numero;
    }
}
```

> ```
> public class P8 {
> ```

```
    public static int contaAlunosLicenciatura(ArrayList<Aluno> a){
        int c=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if(a.get(i) instanceof AlunoLicenciatura)
                c++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aluno a1 = new Aluno (1, "Gervasio");
        Aluno a3 = new Aluno ();
        Aluno a4 = new Aluno ();
        AlunoLicenciatura al1 = new AlunoLicenciatura("Curso1",a1);
        ArrayList<Aluno> v=new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        v.add(a1);
        v.add(a3);
        v.add(a4);
        int Stlicen=contaAlunosLicenciatura(v);
        System.out.println(Stlicen);

    }
}
```

Não percebo porque esta a aparecer no *output* 0, se o aluno `a1` foi instanciado na classe `AlunoLicenciatura` `al1`.

Comment: Manuel Jose, verifica se a sua verificação dentro do loop na classe P8 na função `contaAlunosLicenciatura ()`. É para verificar: if(a.get(i) instanceof AlunoLicenciatura)? Acredito que seja para verifica se é um `Aluno`.

Comment: Manuel Jose, acredito que a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789) possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta no contexto de usar um objeto definido pelo usuário dentro de um ArrayList.

Comment: Não. É para verificar quantos alunos são alunos de licenciatura. Portanto quantos alunos foram instanciados na classe AlunoLicenciatura dado o array dinâmico . No caso eu tenho 2 alunos que não estão instanciados na classe AlunoLicenciatura somente a1 foi instanciado

Comment: Manuel Jose, talvez tenha que rever a abstração da sua solução. Porque na hierarquia o `AlunoLicenciatura ` extend `Aluno`. Logo, é um tipo aluno também, mas instanciado como `AlunoLicenciatura `.

Comment: a1 é um aluno , mas também pertence a aluno licenciatura , logo quando eu chamo o método estático contaAlunosLicenciatura devia retornar 1 e não 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assumindo de que se trate de um projeto legado ao qual não se possa alterar a hierarquia das classes sem um grande impacto, sugiro que aplique o design pattern: VISITOR.

> A intenção do VISITOR é permitir que você defina uma nova operação para uma hierarquia sem alterar as classes de hierarquia. [[Steven John Metsker,‎ William C. Wake -  2006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PBSDKW), 340 p.]

Procurando responder: **porque é que a função contaAlunosLicenciatura esta a devolver 0**. Bom, acredito que seja porque na hierarquia a classe pai não sabe quais as suas classes filhas, mas os filhos sabem qual é o pai. A classe filha tem que se comportar como a classe pai:

> **O Princípio de Substituição de Liskov**
>
> Novas classes devem ser lógicas, extensões consistentes de suas super-classes, mas o que significa ser lógico e consistente? Um compilador de Java assegurará um certo nível de consistência, mas muitos princípios de consistência vão esquivar um compilador. Uma regra que pode ajudar a melhorar seus projetos é o Princípio de Substituição de Liskov [Liskov, Barbara,1987], que pode ser parafraseado da seguinte maneira: ***Uma instância de uma classe deve funcionar como uma instância de sua superclasse***. [[Steven John Metsker,‎ William C. Wake -  2006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PBSDKW), 295 p.]

Chega de teoria, agora na prática:

```
public interface AlunoVisitor {
    void visit(AlunoLicenciatura al);
}
```

Aluno.java

```
public class Aluno {
    private int numero;
    private String nome;
    private boolean isAlunoLicenciatura = false;

    public Aluno(){
        this.nome="";
        this.numero=0;
    }

    public Aluno(int numero,String nome){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.numero=numero;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Aluno) {
             Aluno aluno = (Aluno)obj;
            if (aluno.numero == this.numero)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlunoLicenciatura() {
        return isAlunoLicenciatura;
    }

    protected void setAlunoLicenciatura(boolean isAlunoLicenciatura) {
        this.isAlunoLicenciatura = isAlunoLicenciatura;
    }

}
```

AlunoLicenciatura.java

```
public class AlunoLicenciatura extends Aluno
    implements AlunoVisitor {

    private String curso;
    private ArrayList<Disciplina> l_dis;
    
    public AlunoLicenciatura(String curso,Aluno a){
        super(a.getNumero(),a.getNome());//recebe o numero e o nome de aluno do objecto do tipo aluno ,neste caso, a1 de acordo com o main
        this.curso=curso;
        this.l_dis=new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
        this.visitor(a); 
    }

    @Override
    public void visitor(Aluno a) {
        a.setAlunoLicenciatura(true);
    }

}
```

P8.java

```
public class P8 {

    public static int contaAlunosLicenciatura(ArrayList<Aluno> a){
        int c=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            Aluno aluno = a.get(i);
            if(aluno.isAlunoLicenciatura())
                c++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aluno a1 = new Aluno (1, "Gervasio");
        Aluno a3 = new Aluno ();
        Aluno a4 = new Aluno ();
        AlunoLicenciatura al1 = new AlunoLicenciatura("Curso1",a1);
        ArrayList<Aluno> v=new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        v.add(a1);
        v.add(a3);
        v.add(a4);
        int Stlicen=contaAlunosLicenciatura(v);
        System.out.println(Stlicen);

    }
}
```

Importante ter em mente o seguinte:

> O VISITOR é um padrão controverso. Alguns desenvolvedores evitam consistentemente aplicá-lo, enquanto outros defendem seu uso e sugerem maneiras de fortalecê-lo, embora essas sugestões geralmente adicionem complexidade. O fato é que muitos problemas de design podem acompanhar o padrão VISITOR. [[Steven John Metsker,‎ William C. Wake -  2006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PBSDKW), 353 p.]

<sub>**NOTA**: A sugestão acima é uma dentre muitas possíveis. Sei que pode adicionar complexidade, mas implementar um design pattern requer uma análise de impacto e os respectivos custo X benefícios. Não implemente um padrão apenas por implementar.</sub>

<sub>**NOTA-2**: Reparem que não implementei a função: `accept(AlunoVisitor al)` na classe `AlunoLicenciatura`. Isso se deu porque não teria como torna a class `Aluno` abstract. Isso implicaria em uma mudança muito grande na solução e assumindo que temos restrições de acesso.</sub>

---

**Referência**:

<sub>[Steven John Metsker,‎ William C. Wake -  2006], Addison-Wesley Professional; 2 edition (April 18, 2006), **[DESIGN PATTERNS IN JAVATM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PBSDKW)**: Software Patterns Series.</sub>
<sub>[Liskov, Barbara,1987]. Data Abstraction and Hierarchy. SIGPLAN Notices, volume 23, number 5. May 1987.</sub>

Comment: Na Classe Aluno eu ja tenho um método equals para verificar se o nome e o numero são consistentes dado um objecto

Comment: @ManuelJose, ótimo que tenha sobrescrito a `equals()`. Mas a solução te atendeu? Desculpe se adicionou complexidade, mas você tem que analisar primeiro o seu design.

Answer (score 3):

O resultado é correto já que adicionou `a1` que é apenas um aluno, não `al1` que é um aluno de licenciatura.

Não sei se isto é um erro de digitação (facilitado por nomes ruins de variáveis) ou se achou que o fato de um objeto receber outro objeto, esse outro passa ser outra coisa, o que não faria nenhum sentido.

Na verdade acho essa herança errada, o que fica mais claro pelo fato que tem que criar um um objeto pai para depois criar outro que é filho. O [uso do construtor também parece inadequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Comment: nao percebi o segundo parágrafo do seu comentário. Eu tenho a classe Aluno como pai e Aluno Licenciatura como filho. Todos os alunos de licenciatura são alunos mas nem todos os alunos são alunos de licenciatura

Comment: Melhorou? E se o aluno mudar de curso? E se ele fizer dois cursos? E se você tiver que controlar algo diferente que está em alguns alunos e não todos, que está em alguns cursos, mas não todos? Ou seja, por conceituar errado, criou um acoplamento e errado e manutenção vai sofrer.

Comment: @Maniero, completando as suas observações. Temos que pensar no designer da classe AlunoLicenciatura e com isso inferir as responsabilidades. Manuel Jose, quais são as principais responsabilidades dela?

Comment: Se o aluno mudar de curso crio um método que dado o aluno a1 modifica a string Curso. Mas não e isso que esta em causa. Eu quero somente contar quantos alunos foram instanciados na classe AlunoLicenciatura que de acordo com o código acima seria somente a1.

Comment: É? aí o aluno de licenciatura é assassinado e outro nasce? Se ele estiver em mais um curso ele existe duplamente? Se os requisitos mudarem e esse acoplamento do curso que ele faz com o que ele é, não conseguir mais ser aplicado?

Comment: Estas a meter o carro afrente dos bois. O problema da duplicação é tratado a seguir se for necessário. O que não estou a perceber é, porque é que a função contaAlunosLicenciatura esta a devolver 0 no output

Comment: @ManuelJose, respondendo **porque é que a função `contaAlunosLicenciatura` esta a devolver 0**. Acredito que seja porque na hierarquia a classe pai não sabe quais as suas classes filhas, mas os filhos sabem qual é o pai.

Comment: Está escrito na resposta porque está retornando 0, afinal ela é uma resposta para sua pergunta. Eu tentei te alertar para os problemas, se não mudar todo o *design* não tem como ficar, só dá para fazer gambiarra, mas você pode fazer como quiser.

Comment: então o que propõe para classe pai saber quais as suas classes filhas

Comment: @ManuelJose Tentando generalizar o tudo o que foi dito para trás pelo Maniero e pelo pss1suporte: A modelação de classes que tem é incorreta e trás outros problemas e/ou dificuldades. Antes de resolver o problema que tem pense em corrigir primeiro a modelação, que é bem mais importante.

Comment: Então a hierarquia das classe esta mal formulada ? é isso...

Comment: Só concordando ainda mais com o Maniero, `AlunoLicenciatura` recebe como parte do construtor um `Aluno` e extende de `Aluno`? @ManuelJose, essa modelagem foi no mínimo esquisita...